# How to 'send' postfix/dovecot email files to a new server

Tags: email, postfix, dovecot

There was a working postfix/dovecot server running on a domain.
The client decided to use zoho instead, and changed the MX records to zoho.
Before DNS propagated, a hundred or so emails made it through to the original server.

So inside `/var/mail/vhosts/ravingo.in/rk/new`, for example ...

`-rw------- 3 vmail vmail  24128 Sep 12 09:29 1473672547.M984731P30716.ravingo.ravingo.id,S=24128,W=24567
-rw------- 1 vmail vmail  52287 Sep 12 10:48 1473677302.M251841P31240.ravingo.ravingo.id,S=52287,W=53023
-rw------- 2 vmail vmail 165851 Sep 12 14:08 1473689331.M885291P32352.ravingo.ravingo.id,S=165851,W=168081`

Is there a way to pipe these messages to Zoho, so they show up like regular emails, with attachments, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since each file in a Maildir is already a complete e-mail message it is simple matter of setting up an SMTP session to Zoho's mailserver and then deliver those messages again.

A trivial bit of perl:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
#
## purpose: send the contents of a Maildir over SMTP
##
## usage:   perl this_program
#
my $MAILDIR = '/home/hbruijn/Maildir/cur/' ;

# The mailserver to deliver the messages to:
my $MAILHOST = 'smtp.example.com' ;

# The email address of the recipient on $MAILHOST:
my $RECIPIENT = 'hbruijn@example.com' ;

# The email address of the sender in the SMTP envelope and the one to receive errors and bounces:
my $SENDER = 'hbruijn@serverfault.com' ;

use Net::SMTP;

foreach my $MESSAGE (glob("$MAILDIR/*")) {
        printf "%s\n", $MESSAGE;
        my $smtp = Net::SMTP->new($MAILHOST);
        $smtp->mail($SENDER);
        if ($smtp->to($RECIPIENT)) {
                $smtp->data();
                open my $fh, "<", $MESSAGE or die "can't read open '$MESSAGE': $OS_ERROR";
                while (<$fh>) {
                        $smtp->datasend($_);
                }
                $smtp->dataend();
                close $fh or die "can't read close '$MESSAGE': $OS_ERROR";
        } else {
                print "Error: ", $smtp->message();
        };
        $smtp->quit;
}
```

The above works, but is quite crude, may trigger anti-spam measures and can definitely be optimised in many ways.

Comment: I searched for PHP variants, but they all require splitting the message into header/body.
I'll give Perl a whirl, thanks :)